# How to use Hibernate with JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf, maven, persistence

How to configure the jsf mavenized project with hibernate. While googling i found many guides related to this topic with different form of implementations. Please point out to refer a correct guide on this topic. i am just trying to do a simple database operation using hibernate.

Comment: What different implementations do you have on mind? Do you use JPA hibernate or non-JPA hibernate?

Comment: @padis I want to use JPA hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JPA hibernate all configurations will be similar as described in [J2EE tutorial - Accessing Databases from Web Applications](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbrm.html) + you add your Maven dependencies (hibernate + db driver).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using hibernate, not JPA, all you need to do is put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in `proj/src/main/resources` and call `new Configuration()` and `configuration.buildSessionFactory()` in your project. For detailed documentation on the various options refer to the JBoss' documentation for your version [here](http://www.hibernate.org/docs).