# Hibernate with JSF in Eclipse tutorial?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I am new in Hibernate. I want to learn Hibernate using Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Indigo sr2. I have integrated Hibernate tool in Eclipse. Now I need to start integrate JSF with Hibernate but I failed to find any tutorial or article.

Can any one suggest proper article which can give step by step information to learn Hibernate with JSF in Eclipse?

Comment: may be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844335/how-to-use-hibernate-with-jsf will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try the quickstart solutions by jboss. They are a very good starter for jsf and hibernate:

https://github.com/jboss-jdf/jboss-as-quickstart